# Performance optimization for indexed sum

Tags: c, clang

Given an array of floats, and another sorted array that indexes values into that array that should be summed — are there any ways to do potentially do better than this and the auto-vectorized code? Any applicable intrinsics?

```
#include "stdint.h"

void IndexedSum(float buf[], uint32_t index[], int len, float *res) {
    float acc = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       acc += buf[index[i]];
    }
    *res = acc;
}
```

Currently compiling with `clang 6.0` with `-O3`, `-ffast-math` and `-mllvm -force-vector-width=8`:

https://godbolt.org/g/AVhA4L

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to (pre)sort the indexes.

Comment: Should mention that they are already sorted :)

Comment: Assuming the generated assembler has some vectorizations already?  I'd consider placing const on things that are const.  Perhaps post the assembler and we can see how close to ideal it already is.

Comment: Yep. Added a `godbolt` link.

Comment: Depending on length, you might get good return from threading it and adding when complete.

Comment: Also, if you know length is going to be long enough, a little bit of loop unrolling might help too.  You'd need to profile that though.

Comment: Did you try compiling it without the force vector part and measure?

Comment: One last though - add `#pragma clang loop vectorize(enable) interleave(enable)` right above the loop and remove the force vectorization flags and I think the generated code may improve.  You are then trusting the compiler to help you instead of forcing it.  https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html

Answer (score 0):

Unwind the loop. I'd think that something like

```
#include "stdint.h"

void IndexedSum(float buf[], uint32_t index[], int len, float *res)
  {
  float acc = 0;
  int   i;

  for(i = 0 ; i < len-8 ; i += 8)
    acc += (buf[index[i+0]] + 
            buf[index[i+1]]
            buf[index[i+2]]
            buf[index[i+3]]
            buf[index[i+4]]
            buf[index[i+5]]
            buf[index[i+6]]
            buf[index[i+7]])

  while(i < len)
    acc += buf[index[i++]];

  *res = acc;
  }
```

should provide an improvement if `len` is sufficiently large. I thought about using [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) but didn't want to introduce the potential performance penalty for doing everything through pointers. Might be an interesting performance comparison, though.

Best of luck.

Comment: This seems unlikely to give any benefit over clang's built-in unroller, and may well make things worse by interfering with it...